# Prove that the determinant is a multiple of $17$ without developing it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, divisibility, determinant

Let, matrix is given as :
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
1 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 5 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

> Prove that the determinant is a multiple of $17$ without developing it?

---

I saw a resolution by the Jacobi method , but could not apply the methodology in this example.

Comment: Have you tried modifying it to an upper triangular matrix using elementary row operations?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701702/prove-that-the-determinant-is-a-multiple-of-17-without-developing-it-obs-the-a?noredirect=1#comment3472938_1701702 $$\  No.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. :) You can upvote or choose the best answer from the ones below. Just note the arrow and the check mark next to each answer. :)

Comment: @RobsonNonato, please accept any answer, if you are satisfied otherwise  you can make comment below on answers to ask more doubt regarding this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that 119, 187 and 153 are all divisible by 17. So multiplying column 2 by 10 and adding to column 3 and multiplying column 1 by 100 and adding to column 3, gives us a column in which each element is divisible by 17:

$D=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
1 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 5 & 3\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 19 \\
1 & 8 & 87 \\
1 & 5 & 53\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 119 \\
1 & 8 & 187 \\
1 & 5 & 153\end{matrix}\right|
=17\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 8 & 11 \\
1 & 5 & 9\end{matrix}\right|$

Thus $D = 17\cdot E$ where $E$ is the determinant of a matrix whose elements are integers which multiplied out using the definition of a determinant will be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

$$
|D|
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
1 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 5 & 3\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
0 & 7 & -2 \\
0 & 4 & -6\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
0 & 7 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -\dfrac{34}{7}\end{vmatrix}
=
1 \times 7 \times -\dfrac{34}{7}
=
-34
=-2 \times 17
$$

Comment: It turned into a triangular matrix ,, where the determinant is the product of the main diagonal.

Comment: I was really wrong . The a33 element is -34/7 . Resulting in a decisive -34 .

Answer (score 1):

Beginning like H.R. but then using the fact that you're only interested in the result mod $17$, you could do without rationals by writing

$$
|D|
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
1 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 5 & 3\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
0 & 7 & -2 \\
0 & 4 & -6\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
0 & 2 & -3 \\
0 & 4 & -6
\end{vmatrix}
=
0\bmod17\;,
$$

where I added $3$ times the last row to the middle row.

Answer (score 1):

Jacobi says

$$D=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
1 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 5 & 3\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 9 \\
0 & 7 & -2 \\
0 & 4 & -6\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{65}7 \\
0 & 7 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -\frac{34}7\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\frac{34}7\end{matrix}\right|
$$

but this takes more operations than Gauss.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Adding a multiple of one row to another (and those were the only "row operations" used here) does not change the determinant of a matrix (and those were the only "row operations" used here) but "swap two rows" multiplies the determinant by -1 and "multiply a row by a number" multiplies the determinant by that number.